# Debug Error unused argument (files[i])

Tags: r, for-loop

Hello am trying to run this loop which is reading multiple files from the location and the data is getting appended and stored in Score file but suddenly this error is popping up....

> Error in  unused argument (files[i])

any suggestions to debug it any help is appreciated. I have checked my function also its running fine and returning desired output but when i use it in the loop below the above error arises.

```
files<-list.files(path ='D:\\people\\zang\\Documents\\tdat')

df <- total(x, files[i] )

for(i in 1:length(files)) { 
  if (i == 1 )
  {
    write.table(df,"sample.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,sep=",")

  }
  else 
  {
    write.table(df,"sample.csv",row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,sep =",")
  }

}
```

Comment: To which package belongs the function `total`? THe error message says that the argument `files[i]` is ununsed. This could mean that the function `total` expects only one argument. Furthermore `i` is not defined at this point `df <- total(x, files[i])`. Therefore the call `files[i]` could result in an access violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in this line..

```
 A <- total(x, files[i] )
```

Here the "i" doesn't have any value assigned because you are using your function `total` and passing **files[i]** parameter outside the for loop. So this statement must be inside the for loop.

for an example

```
    files<-list.files(path ='D:\\people\\zang\\Documents\\tdat')

    for(i in 1:length(files)) { 
    df<- total(x, files[i] )
    if (i == 1 )
  {
    write.table(df,"sample.csv", row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,sep=",")

  }
  else 
  {
    write.table(df,"sample.csv",row.names = FALSE, col.names = TRUE,sep =",")
  }

}
```

Comment: I think cannot open the connection is not related to your for loop issue. Debug and check from where the error is getting popup. May be it comes when it try to load files from the path you have given

Comment: yes.. but please check whether all files in your location are getting loaded to your `files` variable.. For that you need to debug and see the place where the error is comming